# Placing a div on top of carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a carousel and i want to put a static div on top of it with the carousel sliding behind it, but the div won't appear and i want it to be centered, the static div is a circle with an image inside it, here is my code:

```css
.circle{
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/50x50');
  background-size: 350px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li  data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li  data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li  data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img  src="http://via.placeholder.com/510x150">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/510x150">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img  src="http://via.placeholder.com/510x150">
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: is the below what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the .circle div outside of the .carousel-inner and then give it left:0; right:0; to center it and a z-index value of 16 (the dot indicators are 15) to render above the slider.

```css
.circle{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 16;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li  data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li  data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li  data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img  src="http://via.placeholder.com/510x150">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/510x150">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img  src="http://via.placeholder.com/510x150">
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> use this css class.
>
> border-radius: 50%; [For Circle]
>
> top: 0; [to pull to top.]
>
> left: calc (50% - 175px); [here 175px because your div width is 350px put half of your div length here to make centered;]
>
> background: #444; [is for checking, remove it.]

```css
.circle{
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/50x50');
  background-size: 350px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  
    top: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 175px);
    background: #444;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li  data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li  data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li  data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img  src="http://via.placeholder.com/510x150">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/510x150">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img  src="http://via.placeholder.com/510x150">
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a few things.

You need to set `top` and `left` as it is an absolutely positioned element. Also set the `position` of item to `relative` so the circle is positioned absolutely within the item.

Then use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to center this in the middle of the `item`.

see updated code and demo below.

```css
 .item {
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 100% ;
  background: red;
  background-size: 350px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% , -50% );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/510x150">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/510x150">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/510x150">
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```